How to prevent quartz job running from multiple azure app service instances
I am using Quartz.Extensions.Hosting 3.8.1 scheduling package in .netcore6 web api application. App deployment environment is azure appservice (2 instances). It works fine and as expected. Only issue i am facing is, after every deployment , the jobs are run 2-5 times in quick succession. The time difference between the runs ranges from few seconds to couple of minutes. After this very first trigger, other trigger happens at defined intervals properly. Below is my quartz config. Any idea.
For example, my job is scheduled to run at 1 hour interval. But immediately after deployment , it run 4 times (green) and then properly at 1 hour interval (yellow)

Version used : Quartz.Extensions.Hosting 3.8.1.
Code
public static void ConfigureQuartzJobs(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
{
    var services = builder.Services;
    services.AddQuartzHostedService(opt => opt.WaitForJobsToComplete = true);
    services.AddQuartz(q =>
    {
        q.SchedulerId = "SomeId";
        q.SchedulerName = "SomeName";
        q.UsePersistentStore(s =>
                {
                  s.UseProperties = true;
                  s.UseClustering();
                  s.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
                  s.UseNewtonsoftJsonSerializer();
                });
                q.AddJob<job1>(jobkey1)
                 .AddTrigger(trigger => trigger
                           .ForJob(jobkey1)
                           .WithIdentity(tr1)
                           .StartAt(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(5))
                           .WithSimpleSchedule(schedule => schedule.WithIntervalInMinutes(5).RepeatForever()));
                });
    }
}

Job1 class
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
public class Job1 : IJob
{
    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            //Call logic classes
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"{context.FireTimeUtc}, {ex}. FireInstanceId={context.FireInstanceId}");
        }
    }
}

Expected behavior
After deployment, Job either should run only 1 time or not at all so that the next trigger fires it.
Additional context
I have tried with below configs unsuccessfully
q.UseDefaultThreadPool(x => x.MaxConcurrency = 5);
q.MisfireThreshold = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);


 trigger .StartAt(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(5))
 trigger.StartNow()
 Without any start time option as well

